# Is an almost surely decreasing stochastic process a supermartingale?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

It seems like $X_{n+1} < X_n\; a.s.$ would imply that it’s a supermartingale (provided it’s $L^1$ (per comments)

Comment: One also requires $L^1$ integrability.

Comment: @nejimban ah, good point, o/w expectations won’t exist

Comment: Yes, this follows from the monotonicity of conditional expectation.

Comment: @user6247850 thx!